# How do I apply a transformation to pairs of columns across a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe akin to the following:

| Date | England | ...3 | Wales | ...5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | 145 | e | 23 |  |
| 2021-04-02 | 200 | e | 90 | s |
| 2021-04-03 | 120 |  | 66 | e |

There are 365 rows.

The columns continue such that they alternate between a location (eg, England) and a generic column name (eg, ...3). There are 190 locations in total, so there are 381 columns. I wanted to use the unite() function from  tidyverse to merge each pair of columns with a "-" separator. Eg, "145-e" for the first row for England and "23- " for Wales. The date column should remain as it is. Is there a way to loop this so that each of the 180 pairs unify together? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to first rename your columns in a consistent manner. Then reshape your data to long which makes it easy to apply `tidyr::unite` and if desired convert back to wide format afterwards:

```r
# Rename columns
names(dat)[seq(3, ncol(dat), by = 2)] <- paste(names(dat)[seq(2, ncol(dat), by = 2)], "2", sep = "_")
names(dat)[seq(2, ncol(dat), by = 2)] <- paste(names(dat)[seq(2, ncol(dat), by = 2)], "1", sep = "_")

library(tidyr)

dat |> 
  pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = c("location", ".value"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  replace_na(list(`2` = "")) |> 
  unite(value, `1`, `2`, sep = "-") |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = location, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Date       England Wales
#>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 2021-04-01 145-e   23-  
#> 2 2021-04-02 200-e   90-s 
#> 3 2021-04-03 120-    66-e
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- data.frame(
              Date = c("2021-04-01", "2021-04-02", "2021-04-03"),
           England = c(145L, 200L, 120L),
              ...3 = c("e", "e", NA),
             Wales = c(23L, 90L, 66L),
              ...5 = c(NA, "s", "e")
)
```

Comment: Thank you - this has solved my problem perfectly. Indeed my next step was to apply a pivot_longer() function, so by simply omitting the final line of your code, you've done that part for me as well!